# Компоновщик изменяет const int* на int const* и выдает ошибку LNK2019

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, компоновщик

Linker (VS 2015 C ++) делает сообщение об ошибке в моей новой программе (код ниже): error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ «public: __thiscall Sorter  :: Sorter  (int const *, int)" ,
Я пытался найти ответы. Смена подсистемы компоновщика на SUBSYSTEM Console не помогла, как и ряд других советов.
Шаблонный класс «Sorter» находится в h-файле. Его конструктор определяется в cpp-файле.
Как вы видите, программа очень проста, потому что эта странная ошибка не позволяет её развить. Ошибка именно "странная", потому что Linker пишет int const * вместо const int *. Более того, если я удаляю «const» в параметрах функции, Linker снова выводит сообщение об ошибке.
Кроме того, я попытался сделать функцию инициализации в классе «Sorter» вместо конструктора... Результат тот же.
Ошибка не возникает, если функции определены внутри самого класса.

```
// sorter.h
#pragma once

template<typename type>
class Sorter {
private:
    type *arr;
    int size;

public:
    Sorter() {}
    Sorter(const type *a, int n);

    void nothing();

    ~Sorter() {
        delete[] arr;
    }
};

// sorter.cpp
#include "sorter.h"

template<typename type>
Sorter<type>::Sorter(const type *a, int n) {
    size = n;
    arr = new type[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = a[i];
}

template<typename type>
void Sorter<type>::nothing() {
    return;
}

// main
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include "sorter.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int size = 12;
    int *a = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 100 - 50;
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }

    Sorter<int> sorter;
    sorter.nothing();

    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Sorter везде с большой а в "конструкторе" с маленькой и один раз- это как понимать?

Comment: 2. У меня так - `Sorter<type>::Sorter` ниразу не получалось, сделайте реализацию этого конструктора в секции обьявления класса (внутри самого класса).

Comment: Я понимаю, что внутри класса можно сделать, но дело в том, что с любой функцией будет то же самое. А кол-во функций класса будет не менее 7, и помещать все их определения внутрь класса как-то неправильно.

Comment: Поправил выставленный код, добавив в класс метод nothing... Ошибка ровно та же.

Comment: Сейчас вызывается конструктор Sorter () {}, определенный внутри класса, поэтому он работает, а функция, определенная вне - нет

Comment: а зачем вы шаблон разнесли по двум файлам? Верните реализацию шаблонного класса в хидер и, скорее всего, будет вам счастье

Comment: Да, это помогло. Спасибо!
Теперь буду разбираться, почему шаблонный класс нельзя разнести по файлам.

Comment: Шаблон не является классом или функцией. Шаблон используется компилятором для генерации семейства классов или функций. Чтобы компилятор мог сгенерировать код, он должен видеть как определение шаблона (а не просто объявление), так и конкретные типы, которые используется для «заполнения» шаблона. Например, если вы пытаетесь использовать a Foo<int>, компилятор должен видеть как Foo шаблон, так и тот факт, что вы пытаетесь сделать с конкретным Foo<int>

Comment: читайте: http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1798717.html

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь!